# how to display multiple rows in a single cell of matrix in power bi or tableau

Tags: mysql, database, dataframe, powerbi, tableau-api

This is my sample input
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjklQ.png)

and Somehow I want this as output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nYYm.png)

This output will also work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6WoL.png)

I tried to do this using PowerBI, and using Matrix and this is what I got using concatenax.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pz62.png)

Comment: [Please, do not post sample data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#285557). It is unusable. Use `UNICHAR(10)` in `CONCATENATEX` instead of comma.